# How can I write the factorial function with reduce and range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

```
function range(start, end) {
  var acc = [];
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    acc.push(i);
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Using the range function and the reduce method, I need to rewrite the factorial function.

```
function factorial(n) {
  // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

I was given a hint to write the function in forEach first and then rewrite it with range and reduce. This was my attempt.

```
function factorial(n){
  var product = 1;
  n.forEach(function(x){
    if(x===0){
      return 1;}
    product *= factorial(x-1);
  });
  return product;
}

factorial(4);
```

that was my attempt at it. I know it's a mess but my questions are, how can i using forEach when n is just a number and forEach is for arrays? since they want me to use each first to write the factorial function I need to use a base case right? I also looked in MDN and tried to understand reduce by following their syntax with accumulator + currentValue and came up with this pseudocode.

```
function factorial(n){
  n.reduce(function(x){ 
    x*range;
  });
}

factorial(5)
```

once again I do not understand how I can use reduce if the parameter is not an array.

Comment: i am so lost with this problem....

Comment: in the case `n.forEach`, `n` has to be an array, because [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a method which is only available for arrays.

Comment: I can only assume they really meant use range and forEach first, then use range and reduce. That's the only thing that makes sense to me. Use range to generate the numbers 1 to n, then use forEach to iterate across the array, multiplying up the final answer. Then get rid of forEach, and use reduce on the results of range(n) instead. forEach by itself on a number just won't work.

Comment: As Jeff said, *range* will return an array with values from *start* to *end* - 1, then you can use *reduce* with a function that returns the product of the accumulator and current values. Any more detailed hints will give you the code.

Comment: Just a note - that last bit of code is not Pseudocode. Pseudocode is not actually code, it's just the basic interpretation of what the code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps to solving this problem, first is generating an array to use the reduce method on, and the second is actually using the reduce method to find our factorial answer.

We can complete the first step using the range method provided to us.  The range method returns an array of all integer values between the minimum value (inclusive) and the maximum value (exclusive).  For example, if we call `range(1,5)` it will return `[1,2,3,4]`.  When we want to preform a factorial operation we want to multiply all the previous integer values **including** the current value.  To get an array of all of the previous values and the current value, we can use

```
var factors = range(1,n+1);
```

at the start of our factorial function.

Now that we have all of our factors, we can use the reduce method to multiply them all together.  The reduce method will perform a provided function on each value of the array in order.  In this case, we want to multiply all of our factors together.  We can use

```
var multFactors = factors.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a*b;
},1);
```

to multiply each value in the array together.  By using the `1` as the second parameter to the reduce method, we ensure that `factorial(0)` will not cause any errors (thank you [@Eterm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635976/eterm) for noticing this)

Now all that is left is to return multFactors.

When all of this is put together you end up with this

```
function range(start, end) {
  var acc = [];
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    acc.push(i);
  }
  return acc;
}

function factorial(n) {
  var factors = range(1,n+1);
  var multFactors = factors.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a*b;
  },1);
  return multFactors;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to avoid getting an error with negative factorials, you can  apply an absolute value function to n.

To do this, we can change

```
var factors = range(1,n+1);
```

into

```
var factors = range(1, Math.abs(n)+1);
```

Taking the factorial of a negative number should be undefined, however with this new line we avoid any errors by making the number positive.  If you want to preserve the sign of the factorial, you could add these lines after you set multFactors, but before you return it.

```
if(n < 0)
  multFactors *= -1;
```

When this is done, you end up with this (with comments now, because it is longer)

```
function range(start, end) {
  var acc = [];
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    acc.push(i);
  }
  return acc;
}

function factorial(n) {
  //Get the factors
  var factors = range(1, Math.abs(n)+1);

  //Multiply all of the factors together
  var multFactors = factors.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a*b;
  },1);

  //if n was negative make the result negative
  if(n < 0)
    multFactors *= -1;

  //return the calculated result
  return multFactors;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: factorial(0) returns an error here so will need special handling.

Comment: You are right, good catch.  This is also a problem with negative numbers (although that might be a good thing considering negative factorials are undefined).  I made a solution [here](http://output.jsbin.com/cebasekasi), but I will also edit my answer to include this.  Thank you.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explaination @MichaelRyan i don't think i would have gotten this, i was overcomplicating everything.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of other answers here that offer a practical approach to solving your problem. My answer instead is purposefully impractical (as written in JavaScript) but aims to teach you other things.

This answer is influenced by lambda calculus which only has single parameter, single expression functions. Dissecting this code will give you a deep and profound understanding of higher order procedures.

We will first define the Y-combinator, then implement `range` and `reduce` using `Y`. Then we can finally implement `factorial`.

```js
const U =
  f => f (f)

const Y =
  U (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x)))

const range =
  Y (h => acc => x => y =>
    x > y
      ? acc 
      : h ([...acc, x]) (x + 1) (y)
  ) 
  ([])

const reduce =
  Y (h => f => acc => ([x, ...xs]) => 
    x == null
      ? acc
      : h (f) (f (acc) (x)) (xs)
  )
    
const mult =
  x => y => y * x

const factorial = 
  x => reduce (mult) (1) (range (1) (x))
  
console.log (factorial (5)) // 120
console.log (factorial (6)) // 720
console.log (factorial (7)) // 5040
```

Answer (score 0):

You are onto something when you say `forEach is for Arrays but n is a number`. So you need to construct the array over which you will loop (and later reduce).

```
var n = 10;

var i = 0;

//use your "range" function to define an array from 2 to end.
var z = range(2, n + 1);

//Now we have an array we can reduce with multiplication initializing the accumulator to 1.
z.reduce(function(a,b){return a*b;}, 1);
```

The function inside the reduce is just multiplication, the second argument initialises the accumulator.

No special handling is needed for 0 or 1 here because the array constructed will be empty, and reduce will just return the initial value of 1.

Comment: You can even remove the initial value: `z.reduce(function(a,b){return a*b;})`. Using an arrow function it becomes `z.reduce((a,b) => a * b)`. ;-)

Comment: Actually you can't, if you try n = 1 you get the following error: `Exception: TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value`

Comment: Only if there are no elements in the array, see [*Array.prototype.reduce*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce).

Comment: Yes, there will be no elements in the array for n = 0 and n = 1 by the way in which I constructed the array.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "if the array is constructed the way the OP is required to using *range* and there are checks for empty arrays, then no initial value is required". For 0! (i.e. `n=0`) this answer returns 1 so there should be a check for that.

Comment: 0! = 1, I'm not sure why you think that requires a check.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and create an inclusive range for the given start and end values.

Then reduce with multiplication.

```js
function range(start, end) {
    return Array.apply(null, { length: end - start + 1 }).map(function (_, i) { return start + i; });
}

function multiply(a, b) { return a * b; }


var array = range(3, 7),
    product = array.reduce(multiply);

console.log(array);
console.log(product);
console.log(range(1, 10).reduce(multiply));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by `Array.prototype.reduce()` you may do as follows;

```js
function factorial(a){
return Array(a[1]-a[0]).fill()
                       .reduce((r,_,i) => r *= a[0]+i+1, a[0] ? a[0] : 1);
}

console.log(factorial([0,10]));
console.log(factorial([2,5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this:

```js
const range = (start, end) => Array.from(
  { length: end - start },
  (_, n) => start + n,
);

const product = (nums) => nums.reduce((a, b) => a * b);

const inc = (n) => n + 1;

const factorial = (num) => product(
  range(1, inc(num)),
);


const expect = (given) => ({
  toEqual(expected) {
    console.assert(given === expected, `${given} === ${expected}`);
  }
});

expect(factorial(5)).toEqual(120);
expect(factorial(6)).toEqual(720);
```